# JSON Error when create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

Trying to follow tutorial on react (Here: https://hackernoon.com/simple-react-development-in-2017-113bd563691f), but I keep getting JSON error "Error parsing JSON. unexpected end of JSON input." I'm using yarn. How do i fix the JSON input?

Answer (score 5):

i faced the same issue & this solved the issue :

try the below command in your terminal

npm cache clean --force

[solution ref](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19072)

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer given by @M.abosalem didn't work but

```
yarn cache clean
```

did the trick