# I'm not able to create react app by “create-react-app”

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

Getting this on console

```
> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall G:\mernbootcamp\testfront\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from G:\mernbootcamp\testfront
Done.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create React App not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843056/create-react-app-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

the issue is: now we cannot create react app globally. It could be possible that you have some old version installed.

Unstall first

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then navigate to your folder where you want to create the react app.
and write this command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: @SUNNYPATHAK Can you install latest of node, npm and core-js. 
```

Comment: @SUNNYPATHAK Can you install latest of node, npm and core-js. 
```
Clear Cache: npm cache clean -f
For node: npm install -g n
For npm: npm install -g npm
For Core-js: npm install --save core-js@^3
```

After updating, try the commands mentioned in Answer

Comment: Hey kushal,  tried but nothing worked, now i changed my operating system and this worked for me. Now I am able to create app

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to my question, if you are facing same issue, which i faced , try creating react app after turning off your virus protection, i tried this and it worked for me.