# Is there a fix to downloading react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, command-prompt

I was trying to download the basic react-app template but I encountered some issues. In my "Command Prompt" (Terminal for windows) I did the following:

```
C:\Users\Danja>npm -v
6.14.8
```

Here's my node version:

```
node -v
v14.15.0
```

Then I installed react:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create- 
react-app\index.js
+ create-react-app@4.0.0
updated 1 package in 4.495s
```

As used in this post ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843056/create-react-app-not-working)) I used this command:

```
npx create-react-app ./
```

Originally, my whole download would get stuck on:

```
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

But I cleared my cache, restarted my computer and redownloaded node.js...

When my app actually downloaded, it just ended with saying:

```
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

When it should've said :`Happy Hacking`

The default react-template is not being download on my desktop and it's just the node-modules that are. Does anyone have any fixes for this so that I could have the default template installed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your `create-react-app` globally and install a new version of `create-react-app`.

run

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

install latest now

```
npx create-react-app my-app 
cd my-app
```

> (npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older npm versions)

[create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started)