# I tried to create new react app with npx create-react-app but it's not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

```
`npx create-react-app` is not working I tried `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and `npm cache clean --force` but it is still not working.
```

Here is the error message:

```
    npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."optional":true}},"fu'
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR! C:\Users\Zee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-13T16_22_36_156Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Remember that "it's not working" is not a problem description, and remember to show [all the details](/help/how-to-ask) because that's not the entire error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843056/create-react-app-not-workin Checkout this thread there are some recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You’ll need to have Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine. To
> create a project, run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

1. To check the Node version, Go to the terminal and type the command `node -v` or `node --version`
2. And to check the npm version, type `npm -v` or `npm --version`

For more details check the official docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You will have to name the app while running the command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Secondly, if the error still persists, there are primarily two possibilities for this type of error:

1. You have an outdated npm version.
2. You have a poor or unstable internet connection.

Comment: I have the latest npm version and my internet is actually stable.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve errors when dealing with create-react-app is to uninstall node-js and install it back again.
Hope this helps