# Create React App not working with no message

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I've tried to create a new React App with every command from the official documentation

1. npx create-react-app my-app
2. npm init react-app my-app
3. yarn create react-app my-app

But I got every time the same result as shown here:

[image: image of the problem]

I tried to fully uninstall and reinstall Node.js; lower versions; I passed from 64bit to 32bit; tried to see if there was some conflicts but still nothing. Every suggestion will be loved

Comment: what is your npm version (npm -v)?

Comment: @BaptisteF. it's 8.19.2

Comment: try this: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && sudo npm cache clean -f && npx create-react-app my-app` 
(ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10132#issuecomment-737650069)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create React App not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843056/create-react-app-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by running this command:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to run it with node v18... The only thing that worked was to use some previous version. If you're trying with v18, try to downgrade and see if it would work.

Comment: How should I downgrade node?