# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../openpgpjs.org\r\n\r\'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am a newbie to React and trying to start a project

npm version: 6.4.1

create-react-app version: 2.1.8

node version: 10.15.0

I run create-react-app newApp , And got error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../openpgpjs.org\r\n\r\'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR! C:\Users\ThunderF\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-> 06T18_16_37_841Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.
>
> npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683555/json-error-when-create-react-app

Comment: @PrakashSharma I tried it , It does not work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue but I wrote the following line and it worked.

npm cache clean --force

Comment: Actually this did not solve the issue , i don't know why , by the way thanks for your answer

Comment: Then you can go through fithub page and file an issue or consult already addressed solution.

Comment: It's a pretty strange but i reinstall react-create and run it and it worked, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and I ran these commands

1) npm cache clean --force
2) restart your machine
3) npx create-react-app my-app
           (or)
npm install create-react-app enter and then npm init react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start